# Transferring values from one Datagridview to another Datagridview on separate forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to have five fields from my datagrid on my first form to be transferred to five columns on a separate datagridview on a different form. The rest of the data is going into textboxes. I have it so when I click next the selected row's information is sent to the next form.

Below is the code that I'm having issues with         .

```
spectrumapp openForm = new spectrumapp();
openForm.datagridview1 = dtSearch.CurrentRow.Cells[13].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply pass the base DataRow from your first form as a parameter into your second form and then populate the DataSource for the DataGridView from that DataRow.